# How to show trees from archive files by default (a.k.a. (org-agenda-archives-mode 'files))?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want my default agenda view to include archived trees from `.org_archive` files. 
From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Agenda-commands.html) we learn:

> `v a     (org-agenda-archives-mode)`
>   `v A     (org-agenda-archives-mode 'files)`
>   Toggle Archives mode. In Archives mode, trees that are marked ARCHIVED are also scanned when producing the agenda. When you use the capital A, even all archive files are included. To exit archives mode, press v a again.

However, when I `(org-agenda-archives-mode 'files)` I get the following error at startup:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: org-agenda-archives-mode
```

How can I get the default-agenda to include archived trees?

Comment: Not an answer to your question regarding defaults ..., but whenever you receive a void function definition it is because the library has not yet been loaded.  Try:  `(require 'org-archive)` and then you can use functions from that library.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no package called `org-archive`.

Comment: The file `org-archive.el` is part of the `org-mode` library:  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-archive.el

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for this misunderstanding. I still get the error when including `(require 'org-archive)` in my config, though.

Comment: I ended up grepping for the function within the org-mode source code and found it here:  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org-agenda.el#L8515  The `org-agenda.el` library can be loaded the same way:  `(require 'org-agenda)`

Comment: Again, a warning. `Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/user/.emacs.d/init.el’:
Args out of range: 0, 0`

Comment: You may have a missing open or closing parenthesis, or other typographical error(s), or code that is just wrong ....  Open your `init.el` file and run `M-x check-parens` and see if that transports you to the approximate location containing the error.  If you don't find the error that way, then you may wish to comment out portions of the file, save and restart Emacs -- keep repeating the process until you isolate the error.  You can use the functions:  `M-x comment-region` and `M-x uncomment-region` to help speed up your block/unblock of selected regions.

Comment: I use this [config](https://github.com/mwip/.dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/configuration.org#agenda-include-archive). I can narrow the error down to the second line. It does not occur, when I comment out the line. Is it at all possible to call this mode prior to loading the org-agenda (i.e. during startup)? Would it be more better to add some hook?

Comment: When you say you have narrowed down the error to the second line, are you referring to the second line of code; i.e., `(package-refresh-contents)`.  Or, are you referring to something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the second line beneath "Agenda include Archive".

Comment: `org-mode` seems to have several instances where a name of a function is the same name as a variable.  In this case, you may wish to try replacing in your `init.el` file the statement `(org-agenda-archives-mode 'files)` with `(setq org-agenda-archives-mode t)`.  The former statement calls the function, whereas the latter statement sets the variable to a non-nil value.

Comment: Awesome. That did the trick. If you make this an answer I will be happy to accept. Thank you so much for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-agenda-archives-mode` is a *variable* defined in `org-agenda.el`.  Its default value is `nil`

```
Documentation:
Non-nil means the agenda will include archived items.
If this is the symbol ‘trees’, trees in the selected agenda scope
that are marked with the ARCHIVE tag will be included anyway.  When this is
t, also all archive files associated with the current selection of agenda
files will be included.
```

`org-agenda-archives-mode` is also a *function*; however, the O.P. seeks to set the default value and this is done via the *variable*.

In general, `org-mode` uses prefixes to let the user know which library contains variables/functions with said prefixes.  In this case, the prefix is `org-agenda-...`.  Thus, we want to load the library before setting the variable.

```lisp
(require 'org-agenda)
(setq org-agenda-archives-mode t)
```